# Get data from select tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following JavaScript methods

```js
// METHOD 1
let categoryType = document.getElementById("create-listing-category-type");
let categoryTypeOption = categoryType.getElementsByTagName("option")[categoryType.selectedIndex].getAttribute("value");


// METHOD 2
let categoryType = document.getElementById("create-listing-category-type");
let categoryTypeOption = categoryType.options[categoryType.selectedIndex].value;
```

```html
<div class="verification-main-input-div">
  <p class="verification-main-text">Category</p>

  <div class="drop-dawn-add-game-list">
    <div class="arrow-drop-down-games-main">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-chevron-right chevron-for-drop-down"><polyline points="9 18 15 12 9 6"></polyline></svg>
    </div>
    <select id="create-listing-category-type" name="cars" class="drop-dawn-add-game-select">
      <option value="Coins">Coins</option>
      <option value="Items">Items</option>
      <option value="Boosting">Boosting</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to get the data of the selected option from `<select>` tag. When I just `console.log(categoryTypeOption);` I get the default value, which is `Coins`, regardless if I choose another one. What am I doing wrong?

These two methods are based on answers I found when researching a solution.

[Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your METHOD 2 works... the issue is that you aren't triggering the recalc of your categoryTypeOption variable.   Reference the snippet below...  I added an onchange event handler to the select tag.  and moved the METHOD 2 code within the handling function...

```js
function onSelectChange() {
  let categoryType = document.getElementById("create-listing-category-type");
  let categoryTypeOption = categoryType.options[categoryType.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(categoryTypeOption);
}
```

```html
<div class="verification-main-input-div">
  <p class="verification-main-text">Category</p>
  <div class="drop-dawn-add-game-list">
    <div class="arrow-drop-down-games-main">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-chevron-right chevron-for-drop-down">
        <polyline points="9 18 15 12 9 6"></polyline></svg>
    </div>
    <select id="create-listing-category-type" name="cars" class="drop-dawn-add-game-select" onchange="onSelectChange()">
      <option value="Coins">Coins</option>
      <option value="Items">Items</option>
      <option value="Boosting">Boosting</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
const el = document.getElementById("create-listing-cateogry-type");
const selectedValue el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
```

This will get you the selected item from dropdown :)

Comment: Downcheck because your answer matches what the OP put as something he'd already tried using METHOD 2